How can I solve "cannot pickle local object" when trying to use parallelization?
The method below belongs to a class and it is imported by a script that indirectly calls it. It is used to solve N constraints independent LSQ problems. The parallelization part is not function, and I am finding the following error message:

Can't pickle local object 'aapy.U_matrix.<locals>.lsqSOLUTION'.

How can I solve it?
def U_matrix(self, V):
    U = np.zeros((0, self.c))
    iters, eabs, min_val = 500, 0.01, 1e-10
    
    
    def lsqSOLUTION(i):
        ui = cp.Variable((self.c))
        objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(V @ ui - self.Data[:, i]))
        constraints = [0 <= ui, ui <= 1, cp.sum(ui)==1]
        prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
        prob.solve(solver=cp.ECOS, max_iters=iters, abstol=eabs)
        u = np.transpose(ui.value)
        return u    

    args = range(0, self.N)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        u = pool.map(lsqSOLUTION, args)
        vector = np.array(u)
        U = np.vstack(U, vector)
    return U

I have the same code using basic for loop and it functions.

This question is similar to: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object in Multiprocessing. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Jeyekomon. Thanks for your reply. I was aware of your suggestion but I do not understand how to transpose the solutions provided to my case. Besides, I do not see where should I write if name == "main": since I am calling class methods from a separate script. Noticeable, my short skills in Python; I am just converting my Matlab code to Python. Just to let you know how important is parallel processing: Matlab parfor is 10x faster than for loop I have implemented in my experiments. So any help would be welcome. Thanks

You may want to promote lsqSOLUTION() from local function at function level to class method at class level (lsqSOLUTION(self, ...) to solve the pickle issue. You must however resolve the closures with the calling function. I could spot V, iters, min_valvariables but may be others.
Regarding the if name == '__main__'statement, you don't need it if the module containing the class is imported from another module, as you suggest

@igmartin: Thank you for your suggestion. I have made some initial experiments and noticed that is working fine. Regarding if name == 'main' statement I am not sure that we can dismiss it; I put it in script that is used to call class methods, and worked fine. I wish you and SO collaborators good luck and success for your personal and professional life.

Thanks. The purpose of if __name__ == '__main__' here is to prevent children (created by the pool) from instantiating new subprocesses when importing the main module as they will try to execute the pool themselves. If that's the case, fine. However, if the target class is contained in its own module, the forked subprocesses can execute the target method without interfering with the pool

@igmartin: I apologise to bothering you again, but I see that if I run the same file for several value o c (extreme points) it goes well. However, if I call pool for different files it does nothing. It never reaches out here:             print('IN')
lsq = partial(self.lsqSOLUTION, V)
print('FASE 1')
u = pool.map(lsq, args)
print('OUT'). I have already tried to put poll.close() and pool.join(), but had no success. The program simply blocks. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help and time.

I am afraid I cannot be of much help here. If you just want to pass parameters to the pool functions, you may want to use pool.apply_async() rather that partial

@igmartin: Thank you for your  time. I will try to follow your suggestion.
